# How can I access log files stored in a watchOS app's container?

Tags: ios, apple-watch, watchos, cocoalumberjack

I'm using CocoaLumberjack and DDFileLogger in a watchOS app for logging the background behaviour of my Apple Watch app. The log files are stored in the app container in the `Library/Caches/Logs` folder.

Now I cannot find a way to access/download/view these files.

For iOS apps, you can use Xcode's "Devices and Simulators" window to download the app container and view the log files. I didn't find a way to download watchOS app containers.

Do I need to add a button to the watchOS app that sends the log files to the iOS app or is there a better/easier way? How are others handling this problem - especially for released apps?

*I've also tried to backup the paired iPhone using iMazing, but I couldn't find the watchOS app containers in the backup - also, I think the Caches folder is not part of the backup anyway.*

Comment: I have similar need. Did you find any solution?